# Explanation of array accessing in X86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

I have the following C function:

```
int sum_arr(int b[], int size){
      int counter = size-1;
      int res = 0;
      while(counter >= 0){
          res = res + b[counter];
         counter = counter - 1;
       }
      return res;
}
```

From which I generated the following assembly code using:

```
gcc -Og -S file.c
```

Out came the following assembly code (I have included the parts of interest only):

```
sum_arr:
.LFB41:
    .cfi_startproc
    subl    $1, %esi
    movl    $0, %eax
    jmp     .L2
.L3:
    movslq  %esi, %rdx
    addl    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax
    subl    $1, %esi
.L2:
    testl   %esi, %esi
    jns     .L3
    rep     ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

I am having some trouble with .L3. The way I understand it is that it starts off by moving the int counter from a 32 bit register `%esi` into a 64 bit register `%rdx`. Then I don't understand the following line:

`addl   (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax`

in particluar the `(%rdi,%rdx,4)` part, which gets added to the value in the `%eax` register.
And on the last line it decrements the counter with 1. 
Could someone help me out with that part?

Comment: In this line `addl (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax` you add to `eax` value which stored by address calculated as `(%rdi,%rdx,4)`. Also, I recommend using https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.L3:
    movslq  %esi, %rdx           /* sign extend counter<%esi> to 64bit %rdx */
    addl    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax  /* res<%eax> += b<%rdi>[counter<%rdx>]; */
    subl    $1, %esi             /* counter<%esi> -= 1              */
.L2:
    testl   %esi, %esi           /* do counter<%esi> & counter<%esi> */
    jns     .L3                  /* if result is no 0, jump to L3  */
```

Basically `addl    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax` is where you access the array (`%rdi`) with the index of counter (`%rdx`) and add the value of the element to res (`%eax`), the `4` is just the multiply of counter (`%rdx`) for the memory access as each address in the `int` array consume 4 bytes in memory in your system.

The line basically says `res += MEMORY[addrssOf(b) + counter*4]`

BTW, I believe you want to check that `size > 0` before line `int counter = size-1;`, and also as `P__J__` mentioned in his answer, your `res` can overflow as it have the same type of each element in the array you summing.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation. The code is from a book i have, but i see you point with the overflow issue.

Answer (score -1):

in this form it is easier to understand:

```
sum_arr:
        sub     esi, 1
        js      .L4
        movsx   rsi, esi
        mov     eax, 0
.L3:
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+rsi*4]
        sub     rsi, 1
        test    esi, esi
        jns     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        mov     eax, 0
        ret
```

Two remarks:
your integer is very likely to overflow so you should use long long as temporary & return value. It can be shortened as well

```
long long sum_arr(const int *b, size_t size){
      long long res = 0;
      while(size--){
          res = res + *b++;
       }
      return res;
}
```

Comment: It only depends on which syntax you like more.

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN: Well, no. If you're not familiar with any syntax but have done basic algebra at school, the meaning of `rdi+rsi*4` looks obvious while `(%rdi,%rdx,4)` is far less intuitive.